# Dirac delta function of a function - can I make this transformation?

Tags: integration

Assuming that $\hat{U}\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable, is the following step:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \boldsymbol\delta[U-\hat{U}(\mathbf{x})] \rho(\hat{U}(\mathbf{x})) d\mathbf{x} = \rho(U) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \boldsymbol\delta[U-\hat{U}(\mathbf{x})] d\mathbf{x}$

correct?

Comment: Yes. It's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, provided that the integral makes sense to begin with ($\rho$ should be continuous, so that we can integrate $\delta$ against it).  The idea is that for every $\epsilon>0$, the open set $\{\mathbf x: |U-\hat U(\mathbf x)|>\delta\}$ does not contribute to the integral. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta>0$ be such that 
$$|U-V|\le \delta\implies |\rho(U)-\rho(V)|\le \epsilon$$
So, on the  set that actually contributes to the integral, $\rho \circ \hat U$ is bounded between $\rho(U)-\epsilon$ and $\rho(U)+\epsilon$.